# jquery Hyperlink and Mouseover text - Hyperlink not working

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I need a little help for a little guidance. 
My text below consits of 5 sets of text each has rollover text. For ex; "Active" when a user rolls over this they see text "Active List of all items", The word "Active" should have a link but it is not working for me.  I have a href but it's not taking the use to the link.

Can anymore help?

```js
<!-- HIDE FROM OLD BROWSERS
/* <![CDATA[ */

var oVTog = {
 toggle: function (el) {
  var container = el.parentNode;
  var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  para.style.display = "none";
  el.onmouseover = function () {
    para.style.display = '';
      return false;
   };
   el.onmouseout = function () {
    para.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
   };
   el.onclick = function () {
    para.style.display = para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
    return false;
   };
  }
};
window.onload = function () {
    var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
    l = document.getElementById('togTrigger2');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
    l = document.getElementById('togTrigger3');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
    l = document.getElementById('togTrigger4');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
    l = document.getElementById('togTrigger5');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
};

/* ]]> */
//END HIDING -->
```

```html
<!--DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"--><title>Hide/Show</title><style type="text/css">
a 
{
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}
div#page {
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    width: 910px;
}
.TogWrap {
    width: 160px;
    padding: 1px;
}
.togTrigger {
    border: 0px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background: #;
    color: #4540ea;
 }
.togContent  {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px #d3f3ff;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: #e3f1f6;
 }

</style><script type="text/javascript">

</script> 
   <table>
      <tbody> 
         <tr> 
            <th>
               <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
                  <a class="togTrigger" id="togTrigger" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Active</a>
                  <p class="togContent" style="display: none;"> This list contains claimed and unclaimed submissions. </p>
               </div>
            </th>
            <th>
               <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
                  <a class="togTrigger" id="togTrigger2" href="www.google.com">All (Without Attachments)</a>
                  <p class="togContent" style="display: none;"> Contains all active submissions. </p>
               </div>
            </th>
            <th>
               <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
                  <a class="togTrigger" id="togTrigger3" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Email Attachments</a>
                  <p class="togContent" style="display: none;"> All attchments to submissions </p>
               </div>
            </th>
            <th>
               <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
                  <a class="togTrigger" id="togTrigger4" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/www.google.com">Returned Submissions</a>
                  <p class="togContent" style="display: none;"> All Submissions that have been reviewed and returned for additional information. </p>
               </div>
            </th>
            <th>
               <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
                  <a class="togTrigger" id="togTrigger5" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/www.google.com">Logged into CS Tracker</a> 
                  <p class="togContent" style="display: none;"> All Submssions that have been entered into CS Tracker. </p>
               </div>
            </th>
         </tr> 
      </tbody> 
   </table>
     
    ​
```

Comment: Just a syntactic point: you have multiple divs with id of `theTog`. Each element on a page should have a unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this part of your 'toggle' function:

```
el.onclick = function () {
    para.style.display = para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
    return false;
};
```

You don't need a click event handler if you intend to let it run it's default onclick functionality. Remove this and it will work.

If you do a lot of this kind of thing I strongly recommend using jQuery. You tagged the question as 'jQuery' but there is no jQuery in your javascript. Had you used jQuery the entire mouseover functionality could have been written like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.togTrigger').hover(function(){
     $(this).parent().find('.togContent').show();  
   }, function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.togContent').hide(); 
   });
});
```

as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fb9uummr/

FYI - @Praguian is correct. Your html is invalid because you've used the 'theTog' id multiple times within the same document.